# Please explain this differentiation step

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, partial-derivative

[image]

I don't get how they went from line 1 to line 2.  Which one is treated as the variable and which the constant?

I rearrange line 2 to get $0=\frac{3\varepsilon}{M}-h^3$, but I still cannot see how we get this from line 1.

Comment: Even without reading the "differentiating $e$ w.r.t $h$" you should see on the first line that $e = e(h)$ indicating that the function $e$ is dependent on the **variable** $h$.

Comment: Oh I realized my mistake was that I was differentiating incorrectly, and was wondering why it was never working out. I was also reading the epsilon as e, an that's why my answer never worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to know the value of $h$, thus $h$ is a variable and $\varepsilon$ and $M$ are constants.

$e'(h) = \frac{-\varepsilon}{h^2} + \frac{Mh}3$.

Hence, $e'(h) = 0$ iff $\frac{Mh}3 = \frac{\varepsilon}{h^2}$, ie
$$ h^3 = \frac{3\varepsilon}M$$

Answer (score 0):

"Differentiating with respect to $h$" means "treating $h$ as a variable and holding all other variables constant".

Comment: Yes got it now. Thanks